# Draw a square on Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I would like to draw a small square, which is 4x4 pixels. I would like to be able to adjust its color at runtime (not like a color well or anything, the user doesn't need to be able to). I had been doing this with an `NSImage`, but this uses up a lot of resources and I can't adjust, and making a different little color swatch in Photoshop to change it to for any new color is a huge pain, so it is no longer suitable. How can this be done on Mac OS X ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way to draw a 4x4 square at coordinate 0,0 (bottom left) on Mac OS X:

```
NSRectFill(NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 4.0));
```

The simplest way to set the colour used for that sort of drawing:

```
[[NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:... green:... blue:... alpha:1.0] set];
```

;)

Comment: This is great, is there a way to place the drawing on a view? Or clear the drawing?

Comment: @Regan If you want to have a view that just draws a 4x4 square, you should subclass `NSView` and implement `drawRect:` as @RobNapier answered (though he neglected to mention the subclassing part, since he probably assumed you knew that much).

Comment: Though really, if your entire view is one color, just use a standard NSView and set the backgroundColor. It's easier and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this. I haven't compiled it, but this is the basic approach to drawing arbitrary shapes on Mac with Quartz:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
   [[NSColor redColor] set];
   CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
   CGPathAddRect(path, NULL, CGRectMake(0, 0, 4, 4));
   CGContextStrokePath([NSGraphicsContext currentContext], path);
   CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

Comment: NSColor doesn't have a method named +red.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[NSColor redColor] set];
[NSBezierPath fillRect:NSMakeRect(0,0,4,4)];
```